# Import huge csv with load data local infile where some fields are enclosed by "

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, load

I am trying to import huge csv files without having to split them up and use phpmyadmin.

Here is a sample of my csv format (some fields have "" some dont) I have looked at all other stack overflow answers but none seem to have my situation where some fields have speech marks enclosing and some dont.

Here is a sample of my csv with the first line as the column names:

```
aw_product_id,merchant_product_id,merchant_category,aw_deep_link,merchant_image_url,search_price,description,product_name,merchant_deep_link,aw_image_url,merchant_name,merchant_id,category_name,category_id,delivery_cost,currency,store_price,display_price,data_feed_id,web_offer,brand_name
3156121231,462496,/cycle/clothing/ladies/gloves,http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=3156121231&a=117981&m=2485,http://products.activinstinct.com/y2014/m09/462496/14723969-n.jpg,33.49,"A close fitting fully waterproof glove with ProGel palm padding for better cushioning on the handlebars.Features:*Waterproof, windproof, breathable construction*ProGel palm padding*Cuff adjuster for precise fitting*Critically positioned reflective trims","ALTURA ProGel Waterproof Ladies Gloves",http://www.activinstinct.com/cycle/clothing/ladies/gloves/altura-progel-waterproof-ladies-gloves/,http://images.productserve.com/preview/5/2485/31/12/3156121231.jpg,ActivInstinct,2485,"Women's Accessories",149,3.95,GBP,,GBP33.49,2485,0,Altura
```

This is my php so far:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE=>1));
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$pdo->exec("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'example.csv'
INTO TABLE products
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(aw_product_id,merchant_product_id,merchant_category,aw_deep_link,merchant_image_url,search_price,description,product_name,merchant_deep_link,aw_image_url,merchant_name,merchant_id,category_name,category_id,delivery_cost,currency,store_price,display_price,data_feed_id,web_offer,brand_name);");
```

It errors unless I remove the enclosed by ". With that removed it submits the large csv but the formatting is wrong and fields are put into the wrong columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated i'm sure its something small and stupid but this has been bugging me for days!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your actual question related to importing your data?  You haven't explained your problem at all.

Comment: Sorry the form submitted before I had finished the question

Comment: Can you output the CSV file with guaranteed double quotes around each value?  Then you can remove the 'optionally', and your data will be more standard across all rows.

Comment: The csv is coming from affiliate window and I want to automate the process eventually so not sure if this is possible. It works fine if i upload smaller ones via phpmyadmin

Comment: Can you provide the CREATE statement for your DB?

Comment: escape the double quotes inside the exec method `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'` and try again

Comment: Try removing the `ESCAPED BY '\'` line, or potentially change it to `ESCAPED BY '\\'`.  When I loaded the SQL in an editor that was giving me a syntax error.

Comment: @AlexAndrei tried this and it still doesnt work. Im stumped! The only way i can get the file to import is to remove that line all together but then the fields mess up

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Removed the line as i dont think it is needed and still no joy.

Comment: feel free to hop over to the SQL chat room and I can try to help further: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11391/sql

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the csv file importing using the following library for laravel https://github.com/goodby/csv